# Specific string recognition and extraction

Tags: c, string, strtok, scanf

i have a file of numbers like that : XXX are unknow numbers

> XXXX
>
> ---
>
> YY YYYY YYY YYYY
>
> ---
>
> YYYY YYY YY YYY
>
> ---
>
> ZZZ
>
> ---
>
> UUU UU UUUU UUUUUU UU UUUU
>
> ---
>
> UU UUU UUUU U
>
> ---

the number of numbers per lines and numbers of "line number" are unknowed.
I just know how many "blocks" there is. (where a block is a number followed by several number lines)

My aims are:
- extracts XXXX and fill a tab with it
- tokenize the "line number" into number and file my matrice with it

What i have yet.
i read a line, but don't know if it's a single number or a line of numbers.

I tried with sscanf, to determine if there is just one number or several, but it's not conclusive. I checked also the value of ret but sscanf always return the number 1.
So it's impossible to determine if there is more than just one number.

```
ret = sscanf(line, "%d");
```

I don't want to use PCRE. I'm sur it's possible to make it with the standard c library, but how ? How from a char* can i make the difference between the two kinds of line ?

Thanks, and sorry for my english : )

Comment: Using tubes in linux should be the easiest way

Comment: atoi is fine for me, my main problem is to distinguish a line with 1 number and a line with more than once (because they don't go in the same structure) 
Every "block" like i call them are an iteration in my process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your line separator is a newline (`\n`) and your token separator is a whitespace (`\s`) then read one character at a time into a buffer.

Once you hit either separator, terminate the buffer, print it, reset the buffer's index, and then keep on reading through the file for the next separator.

Here's some code to do that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* 
    INT_MAX is 2147483647, and so the maximum digit 
    length is 10. We add another digit to hold a 
    null terminator.
*/

static const unsigned int kMaxNumberLength = 11;
static const char *kNumberFilename = "numbers.txt";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char currC, buffer[kMaxNumberLength];
    unsigned int cIndex = 0U;

    fp = fopen(kNumberFilename, "r");

    if (fp) {
        do {
            currC = fgetc(fp);
            buffer[cIndex] = currC;
            if ((currC == ' ') || (currC == '\n')) {
                buffer[cIndex] = '\0'; /* terminate buffer */
                fprintf(stdout, "found number: %d\n", atoi(buffer));
                cIndex = 0U;
                continue;
            }
            cIndex++;
        } while (currC != EOF);

        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Let's say you have the following file `numbers.txt`:

```
1234
234 567 1
4 5
9
```

Let's compile and run the code:

```
$ gcc -Wall test.c
$ ./a.out numbers.txt 
found number: 1234
found number: 234
found number: 567
found number: 1
found number: 4
found number: 5
found number: 9
```

Comment: That's an interesting way, but the main thing i search is to recognize if a line of the file contains 1 or more number
with your example
read a line and get 1234, it's a single number so i put it into my tab, i put every following number into my matrice mat[i][0] = 234, mat[i][1] = 567 etc. 
Now, i see a 9 (single number on a line) so i put it into my tab tab[i+1] = 9 and all the following numbers will go in mat[i+1][0]
etc.
and it's especially this recognition between lines with 1 or more numbers i want to achieve.
For the moment, i read all my file line per line.

Comment: You can still use this approach, you just keep counters that increment lines and words in order to fill a two-dimensional array. When you hit a space, you increment the word counter. When you hit a newline, you increment the line counter and reset the word counter. It's just a couple extra `unsigned int` variables and another level of `if-else` statements to discern if a character is either a newline or a space. There's not much to tweak. Hopefully, this will get you started.

Comment: yeah, you're right, i was too focusing on my read_line function.
Anyway,
thanks a lot :)